# The checkmark is not shown in the mac

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

[image: checkmark_symbol_not_shown]
The checkmark is not shown is the os, I don't know what is going on with this bug? I'm on the newest public beta, but the steady version still has the problem, I updated from steady version to this one. Anyone can show me where the symbol file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common error and it's happening sometimes after a font modified or new font installed or for other reasons.

You need to clear and rebuild the Font Database and Font Cache. To do this follow the steps below:

1. Open Terminal
2. Copy-Paste this `sudo atsutil databases -remove` and hit Enter
3. Reboot your mac

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/08/clear-font-caches-databases-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Really interesting solution, it makes sense, but i tried, it ain't working till now.

Comment: When upgrading ti newest beta, finally, the checkmark shows up,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Unfortunately @gioalexiou answer wasn't sufficient. Here are the solution that worked for me, this was eventually successful, therefore, any of this steps might be redundant.

1. Reset the mac in safe boot, by holding <kbd>shift</kbd> button at startup.
2. Open terminal, type `sudo atsutil databases -remove`, hit <kbd>return</kbd>
3. Restart the mac in normal mode
4. Open `Font Book`, click on File->Restore Standard Fonts...
5. Restart again...